# How can I use Redisson Write-through caching strategy with an auto-generated PK

Tags: java, postgresql, caching, redis, redisson

I am planning to use Redis with Redisson as a caching layer between my Java app and a PostgreSQL DB. 
I have a table called Nodes looking like this:

```
CREATE TABLE nodes
(
node_id bigint GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1),
node_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (node_id)
)
```

I want to use [Redisson RMap persistence](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/7.-Distributed-collections#712-map-persistence) to cache this structure. 
My goal is to have an rmap looking like this:

```
Rmap<Integer, Node>
```

where the key is the PK, and the value is the node itself.

I want to use read-through and write-trhough strategies for caching this Rmap, by using the MapLoader and the MapWriter.

Then, I want to have a Java method which should create and persist a node.

```
public void createNode(String nodeName) {
  Node node = new Node();
  node.setName(nodeName);

  // how can I put elements in the rmap since, 
  // the PK will be available after the INSERT statement will run?
  rmap.put(?, node);
}
```

And here comes the problem. Since the PK is auto-generated from Postgres, how can I use the RMapWriter to insert a node, since, for putting elements in the RMap I need the key, which I don't have until the insert statement will run?

Answer (score 1):

You can get generated Keys from postgres using prepared Statement.

```
   ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS) ;
   ps.execute();
   ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
```

Comment: Yes, I know. But how can I do this using the Redisson MapWriter? The MapWriter.write method requests  a Key,Value pair and then runs the INSERT statement. So, how can I put an element in the RMap without knowing the key, since the key will be generated just after the INSERT statement runs?

Comment: I’m not aware of how MapWriter works, however you can consider Postgres sequence rather than autoincrement id.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware this is an older post but answering because I came across the same issue.
For me, the solution was to use the `MapLoader` rather than the `MapWriter`, using a `CallableStatement` (rather than a `PreparedStatement`) backed by a stored procedure in the `SELECT_or_INSERTthenSELECT` mould.

```
    @Override
    public Integer load(Node node) {
        // second parameter to the procedure is an OUTPUT param
        try(CallableStatement callableStatement = conn.prepareCall("{CALL INSERT_or_SELECT_THEN_INSERT (?, ?)}"))
        {
            callableStatement.setString(1, node.getName());
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.BIGINT);
            callableStatement.executeUpdate();
    
            System.out.println("Debug nodeName: " + node.getName() + ", id: " + callableStatement.getLong(2));
            return callableStatement.getLong(2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
```

Now you can just call `map.get(node)` and the `load()` override will be called if the node is not in the map.